# SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED certificate verify failed: self signed certificate (_ssl.c:1076) Python ssl and sockets

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets, ssl

I have been receiving the following error

```html
    self.ssock = context.wrap_socket(self.clientSocket, server_hostname=destinationAddress)
  File "C:\Users\HIFI\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\ssl.py", line 423, in wrap_socket
    session=session
  File "C:\Users\HIFI\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\ssl.py", line 870, in _create
    self.do_handshake()
  File "C:\Users\HIFI\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\ssl.py", line 1139, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLCertVerificationError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate (_ssl.c:1076)
```

I don't understand why this is occurring. I am guessing that it has to do with my certificates. I have tried the below solution. It has been suggested on several forum posts, but should not be followed because it turns off SSL.

```html
#To fix certificate issue
try:
    _create_unverified_https_context = ssl._create_unverified_context
except AttributeError:
    # Legacy Python that doesn't verify HTTPS certificates by default
    pass
else:
    # Handle target environment that doesn't support HTTPS verification
    ssl._create_default_https_context = _create_unverified_https_context
```

I generated my own certificates using the following commands

```html
openssl req -new -newkey rsa:4096 -nodes -keyout certificates.key -out certificates.csr
openssl x509 -req -sha256 -days 365 -in certificates.csr -signkey certificates.key -out certificates.pem
```

It generated the following certificates:

```html
certificates.csr
certificates.key (used in code)
certificates.pem (used in code)
```

I then use these certificates in the following server code:

```html
context = ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_TLS_SERVER)
context.load_cert_chain(pemPath,keyPath)

#Initialize the Socket that will be listening for incoming connections
theSocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM,0)
theSocket.settimeout(None)
theSocket.bind(('',port))
theSocket.listen(numBufferedConnections)
ssock = context.wrap_socket(theSocket, server_side=True)
```

I then connect to this server from the client using the following code:

```html
try:
    _create_unverified_https_context = ssl._create_unverified_context
except AttributeError:
    #Legacy Python that doesn't verify HTTPS certificates by default
    pass
else:
    # Handle target environment that doesn't support HTTPS verification
    ssl._create_default_https_context = _create_unverified_https_context

context = ssl.create_default_context()

self.clientSocket = socket.create_connection((destinationAddress,destinationPort), None)
self.ssock = context.wrap_socket(self.clientSocket, server_hostname=destinationAddress)

ssockVersion = self.ssock.version()
```

The context.wrap_socket() is the line where the code is failing and displaying the above error message.

Please note that other forum posts noted turning off verification, which is not acceptable in the situation and defeats the purpose of using ssl.

Comment: *"It is generally the accepted solution for this error on Windows systems,..."* - it is not. Disabling certificate validation makes undetected man in the middle attacks possible and is therefore never an accepted solution for production code, on no platform.

Comment: I'm sorry, I just realized that it was turning off verification. I just copied and pasted and never took a closer look. That piece of code has been referenced on many forums and related questions. 
As I did note in the bottom of my post, turning off verification is definitely not acceptable, and I am not interested in receiving answers that suggest it.

Comment: I just corrected my post

Comment: Why was my question closed?

Comment: *"Why was my question closed?"* - You are basically asking of how to properly handle a self-signed certificate on the client side. This question is already answered by other posts and that's why I closed it as duplicate. See the other posts mentioned on how to proceed. If you have trouble doing this please ask a more specific question which is clearly different from the others.

Comment: @GeekGeek4 did you find an answer? I think you can break this down into two pieces. 1) make sure your chain validates correctly against the local stored CA certs `openssl verify -CAfile ${CERTS}/local_rootca.pem -untrusted leaf.pem`.  If that works, then run it against your server: `openssl s_client -partial_chain -CApath ${CERTS} -connect httpbin.org:443`

Comment: If you need more help on how to run these - before you get the Python equivalent work - try https://gist.github.com/rustymagnet3000/e1bad38d30827e2f9f68bedc7534084d